# keytool how to use the keyUsage with -ext

Tags: java, keytool

I am trying to create a certificate with the `keytool` utility.
i need some information on **keyUsage**, i have seen the [javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html).

however i am not able to understand the the **difference between various key usage** like :

1. what is `digitalSignature` and when it should be used.
2. what is the difference between `keyCertSign` and `cRLSign` and which one to use when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Ad 1. The key will be used to create digital signatures of data.
- Ad 2. Key will be used to Sign Certificates and Certificate Revocation List

If you just want to create a simple certificate you do not need to define its usage.